# GZIP/Deflate Error between Firefox/Chrome & Java GZIPOutputStream

Tags: java, http, firefox, compression, gzip

I'm trying to write a WebServer in Java, and I'm running into a issue with GZIP compression.
This is what firefox accepts, and a mainstream webserver returns for GZIP compression:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/3l2cwd7d7yddbei/gzip2.gz

```
1F 8B 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9D 59 E9 73 DB B6 12 FF EC CE F4 7F 40 F4 66 22 7B 6A 8A 92 22 F9 88 25 77 7C 25 76 EB 43 CF 92 9B 74 3A 1D 0F 44 42 24 6C 92 60 01 D0 92 D2 F6 7F 7F 8B 83 87 28 79 EA D7 7C 89 08 60 17 BB BF BD E1 C1 BB F3 BB B3 C9 AF A3 0B 14 CA 38 3A FE FE BB EF BF 1B 14 BF B6 06 21 C1 3E FC DC DA 1A 48 2A 23 72 FC 25 C4 B2 29 D0 CD 12 5D 8D D0 89 EF 73 22 C4 8F E8
```

This is what Java GZIPOutputStream gives for the exact same file:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/2qss90980lczmx8/gzip.gz

```
1F 8B 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 9D 19 69 73 DA 46 FB B3 FD 2B 36 BC 33 C5 9E 5A 08 08 F8 88 81 8E AF C4 6E 7D F0 1A DC A4 D3 E9 78 16 69 91 D6 96 B4 AA 76 65 20 6D FE 7B 9F 3D 74 82 27 6E F3 25 68 F7 B9 EF 67 3D 78 77 7E 77 36 FD 6D 7C 81 7C 11 06 A3 ED ED 81 F9 7F 6B E0 13 EC 8E B6 B7 B6 06 82 8A 80 8C 3E FB 58 34 39 BA 59 A1 AB 31 3A 71 DD 84 70 FE 13 BA 25 62 C1 92 67 1A 79 68 CA
```

(Mediafire seemed the best way to send out the files, as I'm playing with the hex.)

What I've noticed, is that the server's one has a Unix OS stamp, and the Java one has 0. Still, the contents decompress right in most decompressors, but the one from Java doesn't ever seem to work in Firefox or Chrome when using Content-Encoding: gzip. In fact, testing this with some GZIP debug tools online, I found that websites such as whatsmyip.org's GZIP test successfully decompress the text.

I was able to view the decompressed content here:
http://web-sniffer.net/

Upon entering my test server's IP address: `http://107.3.170.11/`

With the GZIP option enabled.

At this point, I can only see it being a problem with the version of Deflate, or the compression algorithm that Java 8 is using, compared to Firefox or Chrome. While I can solve this from Java, I have no idea how to find out where the proper protocol is. Where is this mysteriously more stable GZIP protocol? How can I put this in Java?

The compression method I'm using in Java:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
GZIPOutputStream gout = new GZIPOutputStream(bout);
gout.write(body.getBody(), 0, body.getBody().length);
gout.flush();
gout.close();
finalc = bout.toByteArray();
System.out.println(bytesToHex(finalc));
```

Comment: those files are both the same URL. can you paste into the question a hex dump of the first 128 bytes of each file.

Comment: some browser's gzip implementations are actually deflate

Comment: I added the dumps, and fixed the links. I tried removing the GZIP headers, CRC check, and original file size, reducing the size 18/32 bytes to the size of the original compression, no change. Bytes remain different.

Comment: Maybe you are reading binary data as text with the default platform encoding earlier on. Test by writing to `bout` instead. Or `bytesToHex(body.getBody())`.

Comment: It's all working as text data(HTML via HTTP), but even so, the contents of the GZIP compression don't matter, what matters is that Firefox cannot decompress it to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a blunder on my part, the way the code flow worked out, it was added the gzip header twice meaning Content-Encoding: gzip, gzip, breaking the whole thing. I resolved it.